# Seeking shapefile with count of restaurants in various cities

Tags: data

Where can I get shapefile with count of restaurants in various cities?

I want to get the data and do clusters with accessibility of each restaurant

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange. Some more information would be helpful. What cities are you doing this for? The data sources would vary a lot. Also what have you tried already? Where have you looked for the data yourself?

Comment: Cities are yet to be decided, but they would be 20 largest US cities and EU capitals. I wanted to try a prototype and I was looking up on Google to find data, but I don't know how to retrieve it.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an unreasonable data request.

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start would be https://overpass-turbo.eu/. You can query the restaurants for a specific city or bounding box and extract a CSV or GeoJSON file based on OpenStreetMap data. It has a query wizard you can use to build queries. For example, here is a query for all the restaurants in Honolulu:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“amenity=restaurant in Honolulu”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “Honolulu” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Honolulu}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=restaurant”
  node["amenity"="restaurant"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Regarding the count part, you could convert the result to a Shapefile and then do a [Spatial Join](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html) in QGIS with the layer that contains your cities/neighborhoods so you can get a field with the count of restaurants for each city/neightborhood.

Comment: Note that OpenStreetMap data is not complete, that is the amount of restaurants in OpenStreetMap data for a city depends not only on the actual number of restaurants, but also on OSM community size and OSM community preference, because ultimately OpenStreetMap data is only as complete as people's willingness to complete it.